# Transfer files between 2 EC2 Instances with help of a python script

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have 2 EC2 instances running Windows 10 and I need to figure out how to transfer files from one to another. Lets for namesake call them prod and dev. I need to run a python script in prod to transfer files from prod to dev. I cant run any commands in cmd directly and have to do this transfer through python.

Is there a way for this to happen?

Comment: If these instances were _NOT_ running on Amazon EC2, how would you transfer the files between the computers? Why not use that same method?

Comment: There are network restrictions which are preventing me from transferring them like normal transfer between 2 computers.

Comment: Are you able to change those networking restrictions?

Comment: No, I cant change them.

Comment: What are those network restrictions?

Answer (score 2):

If the two instances cannot communicate directly with each other, you would need to store the data in a "third place".

I would recommend:

- A script on the Prod instance that **uploads** the data to an Amazon S3 bucket
- A script on the Dev instance that **downloads** the data from the S3 bucket

This can be done with the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/), using either:

- `aws s3 cp --recursive`, *or*
- `aws s3 sync`

Both instances would need permission to access the S3 bucket, to be assigned via the IAM Role associated with each instance.

If you wish to use a Python program instead of the AWS CLI, then it would require two Python scripts:

- A script on the Prod instance that loops through the files an uploads each of them to an Amazon S3 bucket using [`upload_file()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.upload_file)
- A script no the Dev instance that loops through the files in the S3 bucket and downloads each of them using [`download_file()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.download_file)

You could use the [AWS Systems Manager Run Command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/execute-remote-commands.html) to trigger the scripts on each instance.